# Change cursor when hovering a child window

Tags: c++, windows, window, mouse-cursor

I have a window that asks for Login/Password with five child windows:

- An editable one: Login
- Another editable one: Password
- An OK button
- A "forgot your password" one
- And a "Register" one.

Basically, when you click on either of the last two, you are sent to a website where you can perform the appropriate actions.

It's all fine and dandy, but I would love to know how it's possible to check (with messages I guess) if the mouse cursor is hovering over one of the two links, and if that's the case, to change it to a hand cursor.

I'd especially like to know how to detect it! I can figure out how to change the cursor afterwards with SetCursor and such!

**EDIT:** I actually found out that WM_SETCURSOR is a really easy message to handle. Basically, you check if the wParam is equal to the handle of the child window it's hovering over and voilà!

But I actually find the `SetCursor` to be a bigger issue.

Here's what I did:

The declaration of my cursors:

```
static HCURSOR  hCursorHand;
static HCURSOR  hCursorArrow;
```

The value is set here (in the handle for WM_CREATE):

```
hCursorHand = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_HAND );
hCursorArrow = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
```

And here's where I set it:

```
else if (msg == WM_SETCURSOR)
{
    if ((HWND)wParam == hwndLinkFPasswd || (HWND)wParam == hwndLinkSignUp)
        SetCursor(hCursorHand);
    else
        SetCursor(hCursorArrow);
}
```

I know the cursor is properly detected (thank you breakpoints), but it doesn't seem to do anything. The cursor stays an arrow...

Comment: Erf! I just had to `return(TRUE);` after setting the cursor! ^^'
I'll add an answer when the 8 hours are passed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So! As I said, I figured it out! (I just couldn't answer my question within the first 8 hours!)

Here's what I missed: (for anyone having the same problem)

```
else if (msg == WM_SETCURSOR)
{
    if ((HWND)wParam == hwndLinkFPasswd || (HWND)wParam == hwndLinkSignUp)
    {
        SetCursor(hCursorHand);
        return(TRUE);
    }
}
```

I find the documentation on this API awful, so I hope my contribution will one day help someone in my situation! ;)